# Firebase realtime database set fields from addEventListner

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

**Solved.**

I am new to web development and I am trying to build a simple web app with firebase.

My issue is that if I write the addEventListner below, I see the alert but nothing is added to the database, but if I write the same lines of codes in the global scope the fields are added.

##### This is not working:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // My Firebase config
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

//adding this reference fixed the issue
const dbRef = ref(db);

document.getElementById("addBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("test");
    let field1 = "10";
    let field2 = "10";
    let date = "2023-04-10";

    set(ref(db, 'score/' + date), {
        "field_1": field1,
        "field_2": field2
    });
    
});
```

##### This is working:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // My Firebase config
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

let field1 = "10";
let field2 = "10";
let date = "2023-04-10";

set(ref(db, 'score/' + date), {
    "field_1": field1,
    "field_2": field2
});
```

Comment: Are there no console errors?

Comment: No, no console errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your code inside a function and then call that function inside the event listener function. For example:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from 'firebase/database';

const firebaseConfig = {
    // Your Firebase config here
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getDatabase(firebaseApp);

function addToDatabase() {
    let field1 = "10";
    let field2 = "10";
    let date = "2023-04-10";

    set(ref(db, 'score/' + date), {
        "field_1": field1,
        "field_2": field2
    });
}

document.getElementById("addBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("test");
    addToDatabase();
});
// Or
document.getElementById("addBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("test");
    addToDatabase();
});
```

#### Advice

To troubleshoot these type of issues, I recommend adding error handling to the set() method to see if it's throwing any errors. You can do this by adding a second argument to the set() method, which is a callback function that will be called with an error object if there was an error.

Here's an example:

```js
set(ref(db, 'score/' + date), {
    "field_1": field1,
    "field_2": field2
}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("Error adding data to database:", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Data added to database successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to wrap it inside a function but it is still not working.

Comment: Did you also try the second code example? Let me know what shows up in the console

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: But the `alert()` still does fire? Could you make a minimal reproducible example in codesandbox or jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, for some reason you have to place a reference to the database outside the function. Thank you for the support!

Comment: What function exactly? That's interesting.. Could you elaborate? It will be helpful to others if I can update my question with what actually fixed it for you